# Rofi, get PID of selected item

Tags: linux, bash, pid

I want to get the PID of an app opened with rofi, so later I can use it in a script. Is it possible?

I'm running:
`rofi -show drun`

Comment: `rofi_pid=$(ps -ef | awk '/[r]ofi/{print $2}')` might be what you are looking for. Good luck.